# Equivalent of "this.SynchronizingObject.Invoke()" in java

Tags: java, invoke, synchronized

I have a c# code, which must be ported to java.
And now I encounter this instruction mentioned in my topic.

```
this.SynchronizingObject.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
                {
                    // do my stuff
                }, null);
```

Now I must ask in here, what can I do to implement this in java.
Is there any synchronizing object in java ?

Comment: There is no synchronizing object as such but we can synchronize ant part of code with any Object using synchronized keyword.

Comment: What type is `this.SynchronizingObject`, and what does its `Invoke` method do? I assume it invokes the provided delegate on some specific thread, I assume, but the answer depends on the specifics.

Comment: It is simply a class-object implementing an own interface. The invoked methods basically do a http web request and process the received data.

Answer (score 0):

do like this

```
SynchronizingObject synchronizingObject = new SynchronizingObject();    
synchronized (synchronizingObject ) {
   change your synchronizingObject  here

}
```

or

```
synchronized  void changeSynchronizingObject(SynchronizingObject synchronizingObject){
        change your synchronizingObject  here
}
```

Comment: More better if we make the synchronizingObject instance variable private.

Answer (score 0):

First you should learn about [synchronized](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/synchronized.html) keyword and synchronized blocks if you are from C# background. It is just a mutex you studied in your OS lessons. Now in order to achieve you can use the below code segment.

**Type 1**

```
AnyObject anyObject = new AnyObject();
 synchronized(anyObject) {
   // your critical section code here
 }
```

**Type 2**

```
synchronized <return_type> function() {
  //critical section 
}
```

This method takes the instance of class in which this method is implemented as a lock.

This should be of some help.

Comment: Thx so far. I already read about the synchronized keyword. But only as a recommended equivalent to the lock(this) {}  stub of  c#.